# C#: recursive search in two different data structures

Tags: c#, data-structures, recursion

I need to perform a search in two different data structures in C#, and here's the deal:
I have one name (which is a string) and I want to perform a search. I have a function called `Exists` which will return a `bool` indicating whether it exists or not.

In case it exists, I increase the name (simply adding a 1 at the end of the string), and then I need to perform the search again (via method `exists`) to see if an object with the new name exists.

This would go on until there's an unused name, which I could use, BUT, in case it doesn't exist, now I should perform a search another data structure which contains the objects that were deleted, and if the string is found there, then I'd have to increase the name again, and start searching since the beginning. 
This would all end in case there's no object with such name neither using `Exists` method nor in the data structure where all the deleted objects are.

How could I approach this problem?

I hope I expressed myself clearly :-)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I don't see any recursion at all in there

Comment: ok, no recursion my bad, sorry, maybe passing the string as parameter by reference would be a solution?

Comment: Not so clear for me. _"the objects that were deleted"_ => What objects? You didn't talk about deleting before.

Comment: @Otiel Well some objects with a certain name can be deleted, and we have to search for an existing item with a name in both the existing objects, and the deleted ones

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a non recursive and simple solution could be something like this ( I don't see any need of recursion in this case)

```
   //pseudocode

    String name;
    bool condition = true;

    while(condition)
    {
        if(ExistInFirstDataStructure(name))
        {
           //increment name
        }
        else
        {
           if(ExistInDeletedDataStructure(String name))
           {
               //increment name
           }
           else
           {
               condition = false;
           }

        }
    }


    bool ExistInFirstDataStructure(String name)
    {

    }

    bool ExistInDeletedDataStructure(String name)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string BuildNextName(string originalName)
{
  string name = originalName;
  while( Exists(name) || deletedNames.Contains(name))
  {
    name = Increment(name);
  }

  return name;
}
```

Or did I miss something?

Using a for loop:

```
string BuildNextName(string originalName)
{
  for (string name=originalName; 
       Exists(name) || deletedNames.Contains(name);
       name = Increment(name));

  return name;
}
```

BTW, I guess your name incrementation algorithm is more complex than simply adding 1: name, name1, name2,... Basically, if the name doesn't end in a number, you append "1". If it does, you increment that number. right?

Answer (score 0):

Why use a loop at all?? (I know LINQ will under the hood)

```
var LastUsedObjectName =
    MyObjects.Select(mo => mo.Name)
             .Union( MyDeletedObjects.Select(mo => mo.Name))
             .OrderByDescending(name => /*Function to order by integer part of name*/).First();

// Now add 1 to LastUseObjectName and use that.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
var listOfExistingNames = new List<string> { "MyName", "MyName1", "MyName3" };
var listOfDeletedNames = new List<string> { "MyName2", "MyName5" };

int counter = 0;
string baseToFindFreePlace = "MyName";
string newName = baseToFindFreePlace;

var allNames = listOfExistingNames.Concat(listOfDeletedNames);

while (allNames.Contains(newName))
{
    counter++;
    newName = baseToFindFreePlace + counter;
}

listOfExistingNames.Add(newName);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create `Exists` methods for both data structures, you can search with recursion like this:
pseudo code:

```
string resultName;
void Search(string name)
{
  if(ExistsInFirstStructure(name)) //name is in first data structure
    Search(name + "1"); //add 1 and try again
  else
    if(ExistsInSecondStructure(name)) //name exists in second data structure
      Search(name + "1"); //perform search again
    else
      resultName = name; //current name wasn't found in first and second data structures - we have result
}
```